# Running a Rust program that is outside of the current directory

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I execute a Rust program when I am not currently inside the directory that holds the program? If I want to be in the `Downloads/` directory and run a Rust file that is in the `Desktop/` directory, how do I use `cargo run`? I assumed I could do something like `cargo run <path of rust file>`.

Comment: What do you mean with a rust file and a rust program? An entire rust project or a standalone `main.rs` or are you asking how to run a precompiled binary (`.exe`)?

Comment: As Optimistic Peach already mentioned, you need to add a bit more information to your question. If you are asking about compiled binaries, the question is not Rust specific, but rather operation system specific. If it's not compiled yet, we need to know if it's a Cargo project or a single Rust file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a Rust file without dependencies, you can do so on a shell/command prompt.

Go to directory that looks like so:

```
Directory
-> main.rs
```

Run

```
rustc ./main.rs
```

This will spit out `main` (`main.exe` on Windows) and you can run that normally as `./main` (`./main.exe` on Windows)

---

If you want to use Cargo, you'll have to create a `Cargo.toml` for it and put the Rust file into the `src/` directory.

---

If you want to not be in the same directory as the Rust file, then you can do

```
rustc "<path/to/your/file>/main.rs"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--manifest-path` argument on `cargo run` to specify the path to `Cargo.toml` (sources files will be resolved relative to that).

For example:

```
$ cargo run --manifest-path ~/Desktop/src/myapp/Cargo.toml -- <program arguments>
```

Note that if you have a rustup toolchain override on the directory containing `Cargo.toml`, it will *not* be taken into account.